# Word for the number being added-to OR subtracted-from another number

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

I first asked this on [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171807/word-for-the-number-being-added-to-or-subtracted-from-another-number?noredirect=1#comment358691_171807), but this site would probably be a better-suited to answer it:

> In division, we have a dividend and a divisor.
>
> According to [this page](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171807/word-for-the-number-being-added-to-or-subtracted-from-another-number?noredirect=1#comment358691_171807), we also have
>
> - minuend and subtrahend
> - augend and addend
> - multiplicand and multiplier
>
> which are rarely used because order doesn't matter for those
>   operations.
>
> Is there a term for the "second" number in *any* arithmetic operation?
>   It would be a word that could mean "subtrahend," or "addend," or
>   "multiplier" interchangeably. Something like
>   "mathematicaloperationend."

The English folks have suggested "second operand," "secondary," and as fallbacks "parameter" and "argument." "Second operand" is the most correct but I was wondering if there is a single term that covers all of these "-end" words.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: I had a prof who used loperand and roperand for the left and right operands, but I don't know how standard those terms are.

Comment: @DavidH I like those!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use "loperand" and "roperand" as-suggested-by David H.

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, a commonly used term is "term." So for example "Consider the second term of the following equation."

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a term for the "second" number in any arithmetic operation?

Normally, math is written with *infix* notation.

```
a = b + c
```

In computer programming, we have a generic name for them,

- With regard to the `+` addition

  - we would say *b* is the *left-hand-side* or **lhs**
  - we would say *c* is the *right-hand-side* or **rhs**
- The `=` in this context is also an **assignment** operator, written infix.

  - we would say *a* is the *left-hand-side* or **lhs**
  - we would say *b + c* is the *right-hand-side* or **rhs**

These words are everywhere. Some languages allow operators to exist that have nothing to do with math where the operation is business logic.